# Create custom protoc plugin in Java

Tags: java, plugins, protoc

I'm trying to write a custom ProtoC plugin, but I can't make the protoc working with jar files. Seems it tries to run it as an application and I've got:

```
.../libs/plugin-java-protobuf-1.0-jvm8.jar: program not found or is not executable
```

I've seen solution, where created .sh script with `java -jar ...`, but I want to use my plugin with Gradle Protobuf plugin and composite build (`includeBuild ...`).

I have found kroto-plus plugin https://github.com/marcoferrer/kroto-plus/blob/master/protoc-gen-kroto-plus/build.gradle that solved this problem. It's jar seem executable.

But unfortunately, I can't understand what exactly I need to do. I have tried bootJar:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.21'
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
}

jar {
    archiveClassifier = 'jvm8'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'plugin.PluginKt'
    }
}

bootJar {
    archiveClassifier = 'jvm8'
}
```

But result is the same:

```
.../libs/plugin-java-protobuf-1.0-jvm8.jar: program not found or is not executable
```

So how can I make jar truly executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid of me, just forgot to set `launchScript()`. So the next configuration works:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.5.RELEASE'
}

jar {
    enabled = false
    archiveClassifier = 'jvm8'
}

bootJar {
    launchScript()
    archiveClassifier = 'jvm8'
    mainClassName = 'plugin.PluginKt'
}

jar.dependsOn(bootJar)
```